# CSS Gradiend - некорректное отображение при смещении размера

Tags: css, modal, linear-gradient

У меня проблема с градиентом. Есть страничка с датапикером, который открывается при нажатии на инпут. Background странички - это линейный градиент. Заказчик хочет чтобы календарь который не помещается на страничке(popup) - расширял страничку вниз. Если это происходит - новое место на страничке, которое появилось при расширении, отображается с градиентом который начинается сначала. Это не красиво, можно ли это как-то исправить? Скрины ниже
До: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня с height:100%; работает это проблема от даты?

Comment: Скорее всего от даты.  Вот стили календаря. height:100% на body - не помогло https://prnt.sc/x23e8d

Answer (score 1):

Задай страницу `height:100%!important;` или без !important, смотри как работает.
или `heihgt:100vh`;

Comment: Не помогло. Все так же. Вот скриншот с стилями самого календаря https://prnt.sc/x23e8d